# Take top 26 of a list

Tags: c#, list

I have the folowing code that prints the top 19 items of a list in decending value order and it works fine but in my list a lot of the top items have the same value so I want every time to take the top 5 but not the same ones.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
public class Demo {
   public static void Main() {
      IList<Employee> emp = new List<Employee>() { 
         new Employee() { EmployeeRank = 4, EmpName = "Amit", EmpMarks = 90 } ,
         new Employee() { EmployeeRank = 05, EmpName = "Raman",  EmpMarks = 95 }
      };
      var res = from str in emp orderby str.EmpName descending select str;
      Console.WriteLine("Student List (Descending Order):");
      foreach (var list in res)
         Console.WriteLine(list.EmpName);
   }
}

public class Employee {
   public int EmployeeRank { get; set; }
   public string EmpName { get; set; }
   public int EmpMarks { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always introduce random "ordering" using `Random.Next`:

```
var rnd = new Random(); 
var randomOrdered = list2
    .OrderByDescending(m => m.Item2)
    .ThenBy(m => rnd.Next())
    .Take(5);
```

Or via query syntax this should work:

```
var rnd = new Random(); 
foreach (var str in (from m in list2 orderby m.Item2 descending, rnd.Next() select m).Take(5))
```

Comment: Exactly the same query... lol

Comment: Thanks but can you write this without the => syntax please? really please

Comment: @Melvin it is already there

Comment: It is but without the fore each part, can you add the foreach part bellow it please?

Comment: @Melvin 1) already added 2) you just replace your code in parentheses before `Take` with the original one from my answer.

Comment: I dont get it, where is the console.writeline?

Comment: @Melvin just replace the `foreach` part, everything else can remain the same =)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a random value to do a secondary sort:

```
var rnd = new Random();

var randomSorted = list2.OrderByDescending(m => m.Item2)
                        .ThenBy(m => rnd.Next())
                        .Take(5);

foreach (var str in randomSorted)
{
    Console.WriteLine($" Name: " + str.Item1 + "Value: " + str.Item2 + "%");
}
```

As you requested, here is in query syntax:

```
var randomSorted = (from m in list2
                   orderby m.Item2 descending, rnd.Next()
                   select m)
                   .Take(5);
```

Comment: Thanks but can you write this without the => syntax please? really please